# unix shell scripting to merge multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have one text file. The content:

```
game1
game2
game3
game4
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/games
10
20
30
40
```

the output I want is like:

```
game1   /usr/local/games     10
game2   /usr/local/games     20
game3   /usr/local/games     30
game4   /usr/local/games     40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN { numRows = 4 }
{
    rowNr = (NR-1)%numRows+1
    colNr = ++colCnt[rowNr]
    numCols = (colCnt[rowNr] > numCols ? colCnt[rowNr] : numCols)
    val[rowNr,colNr] = $0
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++)
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++)
            printf "%s%s", val[rowNr,colNr], (colNr < numCols ? OFS : ORS)
}
' file
game1 /usr/local/games 10
game2 /usr/local/games 20
game3 /usr/local/games 30
game4 /usr/local/games 40
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{i=(NR-1)%n;a[i]=a[i](a[i]?"\t"$0:$0)}END{for(j=0;j<n;j++)print a[j]}' n=4 file
game1   /usr/local/games        10
game2   /usr/local/games        20
game3   /usr/local/games        30
game4   /usr/local/games        40
```

You can change the value of `n` to match the block size of the input.

Comment: how about if I have more than 3 columns?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the numbers of columns, you just provide the number of rows i.e. n=4 for this example. At the end of every 4th line a new column is created *(12/4=3)*.

Comment: ooo,thanks. er, if I use the previous format of data to insert into mysql database, still using shell scripting?

Comment: Its probably find in this case but in general avoid `(a[i]?X:Y)` when you want to check if `a[i]` has been populated previously as it will behave undesirably if the value of `a[i]` is a null string or evaluates to numeric zero. In this case you could robustly use `a[i]=(NR>n?a[i]"\t":"")$0`. I'm not sure if `a[i]=(i in a?a[i]"\t":"")$0` would be guaranteed to work in all awks or not (it works in GNU awk) due to the order of evaluation.